# Crypto hosting suggestions

Tags: hosting

I am new to the whole crypto-mining game. I am looking for a crypto hosting provider that offers POS hosting. I have the budget but need hand-holding as I am not a server administrator. What are my options?

Comment: Did you ever bother to learn where you post? Like this being a lace for professionals in a business environment. Off to.... well, off. We never recommend any specific productor service here.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

Popular German cloud hosting and dedicated server provider Hetzner
has banned crypto mining on its servers after users have been using their
large storage devices to mine various Crypto are majorly affected by this
decision   some   of   my   friends   have  moved   their   Projects   to   RedSwitches
with minimum downtime have resumed mining without making a hole in
their Pocket. Config:

Ram : 64GB
CPU: AMD Epyc 730P with 16C@3.0Ghz
Storage: 480GB SSD
Network: 1Gbps/30TB

Answer (score 0):

Popular German cloud hosting and dedicated server provider Hetzner has banned crypto mining on its servers after users have been using their large storage devices to mine various Crypto are majorly affected by this decision some of my friends have moved their Projects to RedSwitches with minimum downtime have resumed mining without making a hole in their Pocket. Config: